# Why Latex does not start a new line automatically?

Tags: packages, line-breaking

Here is the preamble of my latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

My problem is the text in the document won't be started in a new line in the generated PDF file and just overflow out of the page.  I find this is caused by my personal definition for margin of 0.5cm by using the geometry package. Is there any solution for this while we still use the geometry package?

Comment: the overflow is only indirectly caused by your change of margins — it will be due to _something_ after `\begin{document}` ... something that is preventing latex's natural line-breaking.  since you give no indication of that, it may be impossible to determine what's wrong.

Comment: Can not reproduce. You should try to trim your document down to a minimal example still showing the same problem.

Comment: incidentally, you mention pdf output, but have `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`; do you really run latex, then dvips, and then ps2pdf (or distiller)?  if not, the `[dvips]` will make a mess of your output.  (i don't _think_ it will cause line breaking, but there may be something i’ve not thought of.

Comment: Have you heard of [writelatex.com](https://www.writelatex.com/761334qyndbd#/1660285/)? You can test a minimal example independent of your local system. Test your code, iw works fine. There seems to be another reason.

Comment: @wasteofspace,@tobias_k,@Johannes_B Thank you guys for the comment! I've just edited the codes, which can output an example for you. You'll see the text overflows at the right side of the page.

Comment: @jon @Johannes_B  I find a solution to this problem. I added `a4paper` option to the `article`, then everything seems OK now. It turns out although I defined `margin=.5cm`, the right hand side margin is always smaller. In this case, it is smaller than zero, therefore I see text overflows. Maybe the unequal lateral margins were caused by my local settings of Tex. It doesn't show up on writelatex.com .

Comment: @jon Can you supply an answer?

Answer (score 2):

As the solution --- being explicit about the paper size --- suggests, it is likely there is a disconnect somewhere regarding the actual paper size ('letterpaper' vs 'a4paper').  The package `geometry` usually guesses well, but if it can't figure it out, it defaults to the `dvips` driver, which may have different defaults from what you are actually using.

Adding the `a4paper` option helps clear up any confusion, but if you want to explore your system defaults, there are a few options.

An old classic is to do

```sh
latex testpage.tex # or pdflatex testpage.tex
```

and follow the prompts.  It will output a document that shows clearly whether your defaults are what you think they are.  If I use `a4paper` on my computer, which is set up to use `letterpaper` by default, it is quite clear that the typeblock is positioned incorrectly.

If you use a TeX Live that includes `tlmgr` (i.e., not one installed from your OS's repositories), then it is easy to check and also change what your paper defaults are.

```sh
tlmgr paper
```

will list the default paper size for all drivers (ConTeXt, dvipdfmx, dvips, pdftex, xdvi).  If you don't like what you can see, then you can do

```sh
tlmgr paper a4  # or: tlmgr paper letter
```

This will change the default for *all* known drivers to `a4paper` (or `letterpaper`).  In the unlikely case that you'd like to exercise finer-grained control, you could do something like

```sh
tlmgr dvips paper a4
```

to set a specific driver.